# Relate EE Entries with Location (Region/City/Place)

Tags: channel, structure, database, entry, channel-entries-api

What is best way to relate EE Entries with location (Region/City/Place) example
1. Entry of Simba National Park, 
2. Then i choose park category (Game Park, Beach Park, Cultural Park, Mountain Park) 
3. Now i Need to have location, or choose where its located, (Region/City/Place), sort of chain select on entry form?
4. I will later filter these parks by location, or search location to display parks etc

Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 1):

Lots of option here:

**Use a 3 level category structure:**

Region

__City

____Place

Select categories as required for each entry. You can then call all entries in each category, with each deeper level of category refining the results.

**Use 3 channels with relationships**

1. Regions channel (no relationships)
2. Cities channel (relate city to Region entry)
3. Places channel (relate place to City entry)

When you call Regions you can just show a list of regions, or you can output each region's Cities as parent related entries

When you call Cities you can just show a list of cities, or you can output each citie's places as parent related entries.

Or you could just use categories for Regions, and the relationship method for deeper data.